# Should i use Associatedcontrolid in label control to render label HTML tag?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css, linq

Sorry if my post is duplicate.

I'm using DevExpress tools to develop my website.

Many people say that the use of `AssociatedControlId` renders the ASP.NET Label control to  tag in HTML.

What I need is to apply my CSS class to the label tag. 
The problem is that if i use `AssociatedControlId` i need to have a `Textbox` control with the same ID as the `AssociatedControlId` at the label...

What's should i do?

```
<dx:ASPxLabel EnableDefaultAppearance="true" CssClass="fl" ID="lblDate" runat="server" Text="ASPxLabel"></dx:ASPxLabel>
```

Run mode:

```
<span class="dxeBase_KarnelTravel fl" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lblDate">ASPxLabel</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<label>` element in html is a label for an `<input>` element. So the `TextBox` that is made as an `<input>` tag if it is associated with a `asp:Label` or `ASPxLabel` which is just an extention of the asp:Label will indicate to the .Net framework to translate it as a html `<label>` tag.

In essence if you don't have a TextBox there is no point to translate the asp:Label to html  tag.

You had better add a new CSS class and format the span as you please if you don't want the TextBox.

If you do want a TextBox, then you should add it to your ASPX file and assign to id the same ID attribute value with the `AssociatedControlId` value at your label.